# Where can I find "CloudEndpointUtils"?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am creating an android app with a google app engine backend.

When trying to read the data from the google datastore, I see that I am expected to use something called "CloudEndpointUtils" -- But I am not able to because it is not recognized as a known variable.

I don't know where to find these utils.  I do not know where to look....  Can you help point me in the right direction?

```
    Myendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Myendpoint.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
                    null);

////This line shows an error because CloudEndpointUtils is not a known class...  But how do I add it???
           endpointBuilder =     CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder).setApplicationName(MainActivity.APPLICATION_NAME);

            endpoint = endpointBuilder.build();

            try {
                 result = endpoint.listStuff().execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                // SynchKey = 0;
                // result = null;
            }

            return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CloudEndpointUtils`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/cloudnotes-preview-android-sample/src/com/google/samples/cloudnotes/CloudEndpointUtils.java?repo=samples&r=ae877ea301a35289bee61d69452a51320105ca78) is part of the [google-api-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) library.